# Posts images resized

Tags: css

This has been frustrating me for a while- I'm working on a test site- [www.temp.lpwgroup.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk](http://www.temp.lpwgroup.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk) and I want the featured images to be 700px x 200px but on the posts page- /news They are being added in as 600x400 for some reason, linking to a new image url with that at the end of the one i upload. Can anyone let me know if there's additional css I can add so the full image shows in that 7:2 ratio?

[Image issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRidn.png)

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: The images seem to be linking to a URL which is adding 400x600 to it, rather than the normal image URL...

Comment: You are required to post your minimal markup here that shows the problem: [mcve]

Comment: Hi Rob, sorry I don't know what that means, the link confused me, i'm just looking for an answer to the issue?

Comment: See the image linked in the post now - is that what you mean?

Comment: You provide a link to your web site to show an example of your problem. Will someone be able to use that same link to solve their problem three years from now? No. Read the link I show before this question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are using Wordpress in your website, You need to add a new thumbnail size in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup' );
function setup() {
    add_image_size( 'size-portfolio', 700, 200, true ); // 400 pixel wide and 200 pixel tall, cropped
}
```

then use [regenerate thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin to regenerate your thumbnails